# Как выполнить действие при выбранном select'e?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Всем привет. Есть список через select.

Как сделать так , что бы при выбранном select меня перекидывала на заданную мной страницу. Нужно это сделать для сортировки. Например. Выбрал select "Сортировать до наименование" и он раз перекидывает на www.sait.kz/sort&sort=name;
Просто там формы не будет, и нету кнопки ок. Событие должно срабатывать сразу после выбора параметра select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используй для этого `onchange`. Например так:

```
<select onchange="callYourScriptHere()"/>
```